# Using implicit function theorem to solve a system of equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem, implicit-function

I have the following question:

> Consider the set $\Gamma \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ of solutions of the system
> \begin{equation*}
>     \begin{cases}
>     x+\ln{y}+2z-2=0 \\
>     2x+y^2+e^z-1-e=0
>     \end{cases}
> \end{equation*}
> Describe $\Gamma$ in a neighborhood of $(0,1,1)$ using the Implicit Function Theorem.

I saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3514860/using-the-implicit-function-theorem-in-a-system-of-equations) and it helped me to start doing something.... but I couldn't conclude it.

**My attempt**: define $f:U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^2$ by $f(x,y,z)=(x+\ln y+2z-2,2x+y^2+e^z-1)$ where $U$ could be $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^+\times \mathbb{R}$. Then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial(y,z)}=\begin{matrix}1/y & 2y\\2 & e^z\end{matrix}$ which has non-zero determinant at the mentioned point $(0,1,1)$. So I can use the implicit function theorem to say that $y$ and $z$ can be described as a function of $x$ (in a open neighbourhood of $(0,1,1)$). Following the hint of the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3514860/using-the-implicit-function-theorem-in-a-system-of-equations), as I have by implicit function theorem $f(x,y(x),z(x))=0$ in an open neighbourhood I can differentiate both side with respect to $x$. But then I get

$\begin{cases}1+y'/y+2zz'=0\\2+2yy'+e^zz'=0\end{cases}$

which I couldn't solve for $y,z$ or $y',z'$. Also I can't use ODE methods because I didn't learned it in my course.

Could you help me? Is this the correct way I should follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IFT gives you: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \frac{dz}{dx} = 0$, that is in matrix form:

$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\end{pmatrix}%
\begin{pmatrix} \frac{dy}{dx} \\
\frac{dz}{dx}
\end{pmatrix} = -\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
$.

Solving this linear system at the point $(0, 1, 1)$ will give you the total derivatives $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $\frac{dz}{dx}$.

Note: you get a system with 2 equations and 2 unknowns - the one your wrote. That shouldn't be too difficult ;)